# 500 internal server error while saving data to mongoDB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mlab

I have a simple client that post data to the server, and the server save the data into mongoDB.

When i send the data into post request i find the data in the body but in the process of saving this data i get internal server error.

Note: am using mongoLab to host my mongoDB

This is what i get on my server console.

```
App listeining on 3000
{ email: 'm.email@gmail.com', password: '123456' }
TypeError: object is not a function
index.js:25:16
```

here is the code of my server:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-Parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// set up CORS resource sharing
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
})
//the User Model.
var User = mongoose.model('User',{
    email: String,
    password: String
})
app.post('/register', function(req, res){
    var user = req.body;
    console.log(user);

    var newUser = new({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
    })
    newUser.save(function(err){
        res.status(200).json(newUser);
    })
})
//connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://myusername:mypassword@ds049211.mongolab.com:49211/mydatabasename');
var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('App listeining on', server.address().port);
})
```

Here is what i get on my client console:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/register 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and here is the code of my controller which sent the post request to my server:

```
.controller('SignUpCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state) {

 $scope.signUp = function() {
   var url = 'http://localhost:3000/register';
   var user = {
//        email: $scope.email,
//        password: $scope.password
        email: 'm.email@gmail.com',
        password: '123456'
      };
   $http.post(url, user)
     .success(function(res){
        console.log('You are now Registered');
    })
     .error(function(err){
        console.log('Could not register');
    });

  };

})
```

Comment: Does your `User` model have a Mongoose schema?

Comment: i coded the schema directly if you noticed i could create scheme variable but, it is the same

Comment: And where are you instantiating the `User` model? @blackmind has suggested a workaround to the problem that I think you should try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
var newUser = new User({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
})
```

instead of

```
var newUser = new({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
})
```

and ensure User has a schema set like

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email : String,
    password: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

I assume this is in a different file, and import user schema

```
var User = require(location of file);
```